# Unable to Make a google Sign In (returns that the user is null)

Tags: java, android, google-signin

At the start, sorry if this is the dumbest Question that you have seen. But I have trouble with the **Android Google sign in**. I am making an application to get the Google sign in.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 1;
private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
SignInButton signInButton;

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    isUserSignedIn();
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    //Result return from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        // The Task returned from this call is always completed
        // no need to attach a listener
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(task);
    } else
        Log.d("activity", "not done");
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



}

private void isUserSignedIn() {
    GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);

    if (account == null) {
        promptSignIn();
    } else updateUI(account);
}

private void promptSignIn() {
    // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, and basic profile
    // ID and basic profile are included in DEFAULT_SIGN_IN
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    // Build a GoogleSignInClient with the options specified by gso
    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

    // Set the dimensions of the sign-in button
    signInButton = findViewById(R.id.google_btn);
    signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
    signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            signIn();
        }
    });
}

private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}

private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
    try {
        GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult();

        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI
        updateUI(account);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("activity", "signInResult:failed code=" + e.getMessage());
    }


    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if (user != null) {
        // Name, email address, and profile photo Url
        String name = user.getDisplayName();
        String email = user.getEmail();
        Uri photoUrl = user.getPhotoUrl();

        // Check if user's email is verified
        boolean emailVerified = user.isEmailVerified();

        Log.d("activity", name);
        Log.d("activity", email);
        Log.d("activity", photoUrl + "");
        Log.d("activity", emailVerified + "");

        // The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project. Do NOT use this value to
        // authenticate with your backend server if you have one. Use
        // FirebaseUser.getToken() instead.
        String uid = user.getUid();
    } else
        Log.d("activity", "user is null");
}

protected void updateUI(GoogleSignInAccount account) {
    if (signInButton != null) signInButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}}
```

Here is the entire code for the activity.

In the method **handleSignInResult()** I am ***always gettting a null user***.

Here are the gradle files.

Module level>>>

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'}apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

App level>>>>

buildscript {

```
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files }}allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: have you enabled sign-in methods in your Firebase Project?

Comment: Yes , thank you for your collaboration.I think Marcus gave me the answer do u have any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user is null because you never login the user through Firebase. When using Google sign in with Firebase you need to log in the user through both APIs.

1. Add the following method.

   ```
   private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
       Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());

       AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
       mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
           .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
               @Override
               public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                   if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                       // Sign in success
                       FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                   } else {
                       // Sign in failed
                   }
               }
           });
   ```

   }
2. Add `private FirebaseAuth mAuth;`
3. Add `mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();` to onCreate()
4. Call firebaseAuthWithGoogle() when the Google login is successful in your handleSignInResult().

Comment: did it but it gave me "signInResult:failed code=Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential)' on a null object reference"

Comment: I updated my answer with the missing details you need if it was not clear.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i am getting same error like **"NULL USER"**...

But, the silly mistake made by me was...

I forgot to initialize **private FirebaseAuth mAuth;**

once i initialized variable like below problem solved...
**mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();**

Note: Add **mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();** to onCreate()